# ”ceph health” Can not be used. Module 'restful' has failed dependency: No module named 'pecan'

Tags: rest, pip, ceph

```
[root@stor1 ~]# ceph health
HEALTH_WARN Module 'restful' has failed dependency: No module named 'pecan'
```

but I have “pecan”

```
[root@stor1 ~]# pip3 list --format=columns | grep pecan
pecan           1.3.3
```

**I tried:**
1. install this module for all nodes and monitor.
2. reboot all nodes.

Comment: Do you have a better solution？Thx.

Comment: This could be related to python3-pecan not being available in el7/centos7 repos. They are available in el8/centos8 though